# Redirect to a unique page after password reset

Tags: php, wordpress, function, redirect

Looking through your forum, I found this code and well it definitely redirects, but it is redirecting before the person has the chance to submit for a password reset.

Basically, I want the user to be able to go to

> url: website/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword

Submit for a password reset then get redirected to

> url: website/Unique_Page

Any wisdom would be appreciated. Thank you!

```
 function possibly_redirect(){
  global $pagenow;
  if( 'wp-login.php' == $pagenow ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['wp-submit'] ) ||   // in case of LOGIN
      ( isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action']=='logout') ||   // in case of LOGOUT
      ( isset($_GET['checkemail']) && $_GET['checkemail']=='confirm') ||   // in case of LOST PASSWORD
      ( isset($_GET['checkemail']) && $_GET['checkemail']=='registered') ) return;    // in case of REGISTER
    else wp_redirect( home_url() ); // or wp_redirect(home_url('/login'));
    exit();
  }
}
add_action('init','possibly_redirect');
```

Comment: Use `&&` (AND) and not `||` (OR).

Comment: Hello Fred, thank you. I changed "||" to "&&" in all three spots but the "forgot password link still redirects to the main page.

Comment: Got it to work with a different code in the function.php file :-) THanks for your time https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/lostpassword_redirect

Comment: Glad to hear it and you're welcome. Wordpress isn't my bag. I mostly deal with raw php.

Answer (score 1):

Your function redirects *unless* those actions are passed directly via URL parameters (or Post in case of login). What you want is check for `checkemail` and then redirect. I've used the `login_head` action here, not sure if there's a better one, but it works:

```
function redirect_after_lost_password() {
    if( isset($_GET['checkemail']) && $_GET['checkemail'] === 'confirm') {
        wp_redirect( home_url( '/yourpage' ) );
        exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'login_head', 'redirect_after_lost_password' );
```

If you want to redirect the user after the password is reset, the [`lostpassword_redirect` filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/lostpassword_redirect) is your friend:

```
function redirect_after_password_reset( $lostpassword_redirect ) {
    return home_url( '/yourpage' );
}
add_filter( 'lostpassword_redirect', 'redirect_after_password_reset' );
```